# Json query that returns parent element and child data with condition?

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I've this JSON (I know it's not a very conventional JSON ;) )

```
{ 
   "2958114":{"stockOnline": 305 }, 
   "2958113": {"stockOnline": 2}, 
   "2958115": {"stockOnline": 0} 
}
```

I want to extract all line with stockOnline attribute <> 0 with a JSON query (I use the https://jsonpath.com/ to test on line)

I try this query
`$.*[?(@.stockOnline != 0)]`
that returns all stockOnline values but not the complete line.

I try other queries without success.

have you any ideas ?

Thanks and regards

I try this query *$.*[?(@.stockOnline != 0)]* that returns all stockOnline values but not the complete line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "lines" in JSON, only objects, arrays, attributes and their values.

If you want to have "lines" where `stockOnline` is not `0` - you will have to go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and a custom [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def entries = json.findAll(entry -> entry.getValue().stockOnline != 0)

entries.each { entry ->
    log.info('"' + entry.getKey() + '":' + new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(entry.getValue()).toString())
}
```

Demo:

[image]